# how should this ``rfc 1071`` be implemented in python?

Tags: python, scapy, checksum, rfc

This is my code to calculate the checksum manually using RFC 1071:

```
from scapy.all import *

data = IP(src='192.168.1.34', dst='192.168.1.1')

convert_packet_bytes = bytes(data)

mylst = []

for start,end in zip(convert_packet_bytes[0::1], convert_packet_bytes[2::1]):
    multi = start*256+end    
    mylst.append(multi)

print(sum(mylst) % 65535)

my_code_result = 64954
```

And this calculates the checksum using Scapy's `show2`:

```
from scapy.all import *

ip_packet = IP(src='192.168.1.34', dst='192.168.1.1')

ip_packet .show2()

scapy_result : 63349
```

In the first code i am trying to implement a `checksum calcolator` using `rfc 1071` in python to calculate the `checksum` for the ip protocol in `scapy` and in the second code i am using the scapy's `show2` function to calculate the ip `checksum` and compare it with my own implementation of `checksum` in the first code using `rfc 1071`

but the problem is the first checksum code result which is my code is `64954` and the second checksum code which is from the scapy's `show2` function is `63349` they are not the same i am trying to get the same result by implementing the `rfc 1071` in python

Comment: I don't think your slices are doing what you intend. You're not getting pairs of adjacent bytes without overlaps. You're getting pairs offset by two (skipping a byte in between them) and using every byte (other than a few at the ends) twice. Try `zip(convert_packet_bytes[0::2], convert_packet_bytes[1::2])` (or, if you don't mind some iterator shenanigans, `zip(*[iter(convert_packets_bytes)]*2)`). I also don't think you're doing the ones-complement addition correctly, you need to add in the overflow that you're discarding with the mod operator.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs by `|\xe7` when i convert the `IP()` packet to bytes :

`b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00|\xe7\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01'`

so we have to remove `|\xe7` :

`b'E\x00\x00\x14\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01'`

and then calculate the checksum :

```
from scapy.all import *

data = IP()

packet_bytes = bytes(data)
convert_packet_bytes = packet_bytes[0:10] + packet_bytes[12:]

mylst = []

for start,end in zip(convert_packet_bytes[0::2], convert_packet_bytes[1::2]):
    #print(start, end)
    multi = start*256+end    
    mylst.append(multi)

print(-sum(mylst) % 65535)
```

result is : `31975`

if we go to scapy and use `show2()` to calculate the checksum of `IP()` we will find it the same :

```
from scapy.all import *

ip_packet = IP(src='192.168.1.34', dst='192.168.1.1')

ip_packet .show2()
```

result is : `0x7ce7` == `31975`

and the problem is solved perfectly